# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '}' In Wordpress plugin activation php 5.5

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm getting this error when trying to activate a custom plugin on my localhost, I have a working copy of the website working that runs php 5.2, where this problem does not occur.

localhost:
PHP Version 5.5.14

this is the offending snippet, at the last line:

```
...
// Widget Backend
public function form( $instance ) {
    if ( isset( $instance[ 'title' ] ) ) {
        $title = $instance[ 'title' ];
    } else {
        $title = __( 'Delivery', 'delivery_widget_domain' );
    }

    if (isset($instance['sub_title'])){
        $sub_title = $instance['sub_title'];
    } else {
        $sub_title = __('escolha uma categoria', 'delivery_widget_domain');
    }
    // Widget admin form
    ?>
    <p>
        <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'title' ); ?>"><?php _e( 'Title:' ); ?></label>
        <input class="widefat" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'title' ); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name( 'title' ); ?>" type="text" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $title ); ?>" />
    </p>
    <p>
        <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('sub_title'); ?>"><?php _e('Sub Título:'); ?></label>
        <input class="widefat" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('sub_title');?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name('sub_title'); ?>" type="text" value="<?php echo esc_attr($sub_title); ?>" />
    </p>
  <?php
} // <----- this line
...
```

Why this is happening?

EDIT: paste bin of the file, the error is on line 55
http://pastebin.com/hHxnfsDA

```
error message ( ! ) Parse error: parse error in /.../widgets/delivery.php on line 55
Call Stack
#   Time    Memory  Function    Location
1   0.0013  391472  {main}( )   ../plugins.php:0
2   0.8336  47175152    plugin_sandbox_scrape( )    ../plugins.php:153
3   0.8337  47177328    include( '/.../plugins/portalsabores-plugin/portalsabores-plugin.php' ) ../plugins.php:151
```

and on cli:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '}' in Sites/portalsabores/wp-content/plugins/portalsabores-plugin/widgets/delivery.php on line 55
```

Comment: On which line do you get the error and which line is this line, please mark it!

Comment: In this piece of code, there are no syntax error(s)

Comment: @Rizier123, just marked it!
lolka_bolka, just added the error messages

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first PHP tag (line 1 of the Pastebin file) needs to be `<?php` (and not `<?`) if you want to open `<?php` in the rest of the file.

Look at this test script :

```
<?
if (true)
{
    ?>
    <?
}

if (true)
{
    ?>
    <?php
}
?>
```

Online evaluation of this test script: http://3v4l.org/tg8SU

PHP works as expected when you open PHP code with `<?` line 5, but it will detect a parse error at line 12.

Comment: @igrossiter It solved the problem for me. Did the error change ?

Comment: I'm very sorry, the error really changed for another file with the same problem, it worked! I LOVE you man!

Answer (score 0):

If you are not inside a class, remove "public"  from "public function form".

Comment: thanks, but it is inside a class, just added a pastebin with all of the file